# Meteor display locations from collection in Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm using the sample code in this [tutorial](http://www.vanopstal.eu/blog/reactive-google-maps-with-meteor) to display a collection of locations using the `dburles:google-maps` package. The only thing I needed to do in addition to the steps in the tutorial was to add the meteor sessions package (which isn't included by default in the latest version of meteor).

However, when I debug the site, although the map loads fine and centers correctly, the `places` collection does not seem to have been loaded and the `Meteor.startup()` also doesn't appear to have run (console.log inside the function isn't printing).

If I execute a `Places.find().fetch()` in the browser console window, an empty collection of objects is returned.

What am I missing here?

```js
Places = new Mongo.Collection('places');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var lookup = [];

  Meteor.startup(function() {
    GoogleMaps.load({v: '3', key: 'API_KEY'});
  });

  Template.map.onCreated(function() {
    var self = this;

    GoogleMaps.ready('map', function(map) {
      self.autorun(function() {
        getBox();

        var handle = Meteor.subscribe('places', Session.get('box'));
        if (handle.ready()) {
          var places = Places.find().fetch();

          _.each(places, function(place) {
            var lat = place.location.coordinates[0];
            var lng = place.location.coordinates[1];

            if (!_.contains(lookup, lat+','+lng)) {
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                map: GoogleMaps.maps.map.instance
              });
              lookup.push(lat+','+lng);
            }
          });
        }
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(map.instance, 'dragend', function(e){
        getBox();
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(map.instance, 'zoom_changed', function(e){
        getBox();
      });
    });
  });

  Template.map.helpers({
    mapOptions: function() {
      if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
        return {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.370216, 4.895168),
          zoom: 14
        };
      }
    },
    places: function() {
      return Places.find();
    }
  });

  function getBox() {
    var bounds = GoogleMaps.maps.map.instance.getBounds();
    var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
    Session.set('box', [[sw.lat(),sw.lng()], [ne.lat(),ne.lng()]]);
  }
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('places', function(box) {
    var find = {
      location: {
        $geoWithin: {
          $box: box
        }
      }
    };

    return Places.find(find);
  });

  Meteor.startup(function() {
    console.log('here');
    var data = [
      {
        "name": "Nieuwmarkt, Amsterdam",
        "location": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": {
            "lat": 52.372466,
            "lng": 4.900722
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Waterlooplein, Amsterdam",
        "location": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": {
            "lat": 52.368078,
            "lng": 4.902281
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Anne Frank Huis, Amsterdam",
        "location": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": {
            "lat": 52.375218,
            "lng": 4.883977
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Dappermarkt, Amsterdam",
        "location": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": {
            "lat": 52.362222,
            "lng": 4.927778
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Westergas, Amsterdam",
        "location": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": {
            "lat": 52.385946,
            "lng": 4.875867
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Ransdorp, Amsterdam",
        "location": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": {
            "lat": 52.392954,
            "lng": 4.993593
          }
        }
      },
    ];

    if(!Places.find().count()) {
      _.each(data, function(place) {
        Places.insert({
          name: place.name,
          location: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [
              place.location.coordinates.lat,
              place.location.coordinates.lng
            ]
          }
        })
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
    padding: 20px;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}

.map {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
}

.places {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <title>Reactive Google Maps with Meteor</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Reactive Google Maps with Meteor</h1>
{{> map}}
</body>

<template name="map">
 <div class="map">
  {{> googleMap name="map" options=mapOptions}}
 </div>
 <div class="places">
  {{#each places}}
   <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
 </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Might not be problematic since you do the mistake in both `getBox` and DB bootstrap (and so does your tutorial), but the coordinates order should be the same as GeoJSON spec, i.e [`[longitude, latitude]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#overview)

Comment: @ghybs Hmm, I'm not sure. I'm using a meteor package that uses the Google Maps JS API which does use lat, long: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

Comment: Google uses [lat, lng] but GeoJSON uses [lng, lat]. It is a matter of [convention](https://macwright.org/lonlat/). MongoDB geospatial feature expects the GeoJSON convention.